# Is there any way to achieve bootstrap like push and pull in MDL(Materail design)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, material-design, material-design-lite

Is there any way via which i can achieve bootstrap push and pull in MDL(material designs lite).

Usecase that I am working on is 2 cols side by side appearing on desktop like this:

```
A(mdl-cell-col--6)     B(mdl-cell-col--6)
```

But on tablet I want to reverse the order: so new order will be on tablet view will be

```
B(mdl-cell-col--6)     A(mdl-cell-col--6)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `mdl-cell--order-N` classes for that (*with the `-tablet` suffix*).

So

add `mdl-cell--order-2-tablet` for A and `mdl-cell--order-1-tablet` for B

You should also add `mdl-cell--4-col-tablet` to both as the `tablet` is assumed to be 8 columns

```css
.mdl-cell {
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--order-2-tablet">A</div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--order-1-tablet">B</div>
    </div>
```